# how to read a specific field from an array returned by the model in the controller itself

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I have a function in the controller "thisTopic" that has following:

```
$viewdata = array();
$viewdata['reply']   = $this->disc->get_all_replies($topic_id);
$viewdata['firstReply']= $this->disc->get_firstReply();
```

In the model:

```
public function get_all_replies($topic_id){

    return $results =  $this->db->select('*')
                     ->from('disc_replies')
                     ->join('users', 'users.id = disc_replies.users_id')
                     ->where('topic_id',$topic_id)
                     ->get()->result();
}

public function get_firstReply($reply_id){

    return $results =  $this->db->select('*')
                     ->from('disc_firstReply')
                     ->join('users', 'users.id = disc_firstReply.users_id')
                     ->where('reply_id',$reply_id)
                     ->get()->result();
}
```

The `disc_replies` table has the following columns:

```
1. reply_id
2. topic_id
3. users_id
4. replied_on
```

from the `$viewdata['reply']` I want to read the reply_id field of the first row and sent it as the parameter to the `get_firstReply()` function.

This is what I tried so far:

```
$viewdata['firstReply']= $this->disc->get_firstReply($viewdata['reply'][0]['reply_id']);

$viewdata['firstReply']= $this->disc->get_firstReply($viewdata['reply']['reply_id']);
```

But nothing works, any help to solve this problem is really appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In order to use this  `$viewdata['reply'][0]` (0 pointed array) in codeigniter, You have to format array as objective array.

This

```
->get()->result();
```

should change as

```
->get()->result_array();
```

---

> You can check the format of the array by using this `print_r($viewdata['reply'])`

---

> Make sure `$viewdata['reply']` is not empty